# Understanding docker-compose of VS2017 webform application

Tags: asp.net, docker, docker-compose, visual-studio-2017

I'm creating a Webform application that I try to containerize.
I use VS2017, create the default webform app, and add docker support.

If I F5 the application, it's working (hopefully)

The "add docker support" adds many files :

1) a Dockerfile, with

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

I understand it's based on the aspnet:4.6.2 image and that it copy the files from obj/docker/publish to put them in the container.

My problem is that I have no files published on this directory. Of course if I docker build, I have an error (it can't find files in obj/docker/publish). Remember, with F5 it's working.

But there's additionnal files.

2) Docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'

services:
  legacywebapp:
    image: legacywebapp
    build:
      context: .\LegacyWebApp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

If I understand well, it creates a legacywebapp services based on the dockerfile. The one that is not working, and still no "obj/docker/publish"

3) docker-compose.override.yml with :

```
version: '3'

services:
  legacywebapp:
    ports:
      - "80"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

Ok, I assume it exposes the port 80 (why not in the first file ? but anyway, for modularity it's better I suppose).

If I try

```
docker-compose -f .\docker-compose.yml -f .\docker-compose.override.yml build
```

of course I have an error :

```
Step 4/4 : COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ERROR: Service 'legacywebapp' failed to build: COPY failed: GetFileAttributesEx \\?\C:\windows\TEMP\docker-builder798755009\obj\Docker\publish: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Why is it working when I F5 in visual studio ? Let's look in the build output of VS, I can see the command line :

```
docker-compose -f "C:\Users\...\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\Users\...\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "C:\Users\...\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose15539612722162891187 up -d --build
```

So, there's another file, I suppose for debugging :

4) docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  legacywebapp:
    image: legacywebapp:dev
    build:
      args:
        source: obj/Docker/empty/
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\...\LegacyWebApp:C:\inetpub\wwwroot
      - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger:C:\remote_debugger:ro
    labels:
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.program: "C:\\app\\bin/LegacyWebApp.dll"
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.workingdirectory: "C:\\app"
```

And again, no obj/docker/publish. What is the obj/Docker/empty/ ?

How can I build correctly the image ? For example if I want to publish it in a private repository...

Comment: After you added the Docker support if you "F5 the application" you see your sample Web Form working? If yes, it means your Docker image is working. Check Visual Studio Build Output. And if you are trying to run the build commands from outside Visual Studio it is not working because the "Source" is an environment variable passed by Visual Studio at build time.